# Sitecore Webform for Marketer Save to Database FormID

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I have a form created in sitecore WFFM and exported into ascx control.

My form has 2 save actions:

1. Save to Database and
2. Send Mail Message

In Save to Database action, a new row is inserted into WFFM tables.

I want to get the submitted form id (which is the id from form table) and insert into the send mail message as part of the message. Is there a WFFm function that I can call to get the id? I am not talking about `this.FormID` which is the main form id, but the id of just submitted form instance.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to that question is, out of the box, no.  The only out of the box values you can use on the send email are the values in the form itself.  You can easily do it with a custom data call, but out of the box, no.